# Group and then expand a record in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following data in a collection.

```
> db.person.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("573a30a9dcf15c037f943f27"),
        "name" : "Mark",
        "age" : 30,
        "country" : "US"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("573a30b9dcf15c037f943f28"),
        "name" : "John",
        "age" : 34,
        "country" : "FR"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("573a30d1dcf15c037f943f29"),
        "name" : "Rodrigo",
        "age" : 23,
        "country" : "IT"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("573a3194dcf15c037f943f2a"),
        "name" : "Steve",
        "age" : 23,
        "country" : "US"
}
```

I am trying to find out the document of the eldest person in each of the countries. For example, the following should be the result for the above data.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("573a30a9dcf15c037f943f27"),
        "name" : "Mark",
        "age" : 30,
        "country" : "US"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("573a30b9dcf15c037f943f28"),
        "name" : "John",
        "age" : 34,
        "country" : "FR"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("573a30d1dcf15c037f943f29"),
        "name" : "Robert",
        "age" : 23,
        "country" : "IT"
}
```

I have tried with aggregates but it doesn't help. Is it actually possible to do this kind of operations in Mongo DB? If yes, please share the solution.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612660/select-max-with-group-by-in-mongodb

Comment: What would you like to do if two documents have the same "age" value which corresponds to  the maximum for their "country"?

Answer (score 2):

You actually can do this, if I understand you right.  What you are trying to do is group by country and pick the highest age.

Something like this might work:

```
db.person.aggregate([
  {$sort: {country: 1, age: 1}},
  {$group: 
      {_id: "$country",
       doc_id: {$last: "$_id"},
       age: {$last: "$age"},
       name: {$last: "$name"}}
  }
])
```

This will give you the highest in each, with documents having IDs corresponding to the country, and including all the info of the original document.  You can add anything you want to the pipeline after the group, for example if you wanted to reshape the documents to have different property names.