# Highscores in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've made a small HTML5 game with a highscores feature. At the end of every game, my node server stores `name`, `score` and `userId` (a number unique for each player) in a Mongo database, and then orders it by `score` and sends back the top 3.

So far it works, but I want to find a way so that each player can appear on the highscore table only once.

So if the scores would be:

```
Player A, 100
Player A, 99
Player A, 98
Player B, 97
Player B, 91
Player C, 96
```

then I would like to display:

```
Player A, 100
Player B, 97
Player C , 96
```

Is there a way to do this in Mongo? It's the first time I'm using it, and don't even now what this function would be called...

Comment: use aggregation. First, sort by score, then group bu userID. query id `db.collection.aggregate([{$sort: {score: -1}}, {$group: {_id: "$userId", score: {$first: "$score"}, name: {$first: "$name"}}}])`

Comment: Or you could forst group and then sort `db.collection.aggregate([{$group: {_id: "$userId", score: {$max: "$score"}, name: {$first: "$name"}}},{$sort: {score: -1}}])`. Regardless, @felix should post the answer, so you can accept it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select Max() with "group by" in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612660/select-max-with-group-by-in-mongodb)