# Find and count in the same query in MongoDB

Tags: mysql, mongodb

How exactly would one use the MongoDB aggregate function to get the same result as the following MySQL query?

```
sqlite> SELECT company, COUNT(*), MAX(salary) FROM Employees GROUP BY company;
```

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13275889/2554537 or https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perform-min-max-with-mongodb-aggregation

Comment: You will find this [SQL to Aggregation Mapping Chart](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/index.html) useful to translate your SQL query to MongoDB query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $group: { _id: "$company", count: { $sum: 1 }, max: { $max: "$salary" } } },
  { $project: { _id: 0, company: "$_id", count: 1, max: 1 } },
]);
```

`$project` stage is added at the end of the pipeline for just renaming the `_id` field to `company` in the final output